# onCreateOptionsMenu in a Fragment lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I found a really strange behavior in the `Fragment` lifecycle.

After several tests on one `Fragment`, I realized than I got this execution order every time:

1. onCreateView()
2. onStart()
3. onCreateOptionsMenu()

I am really surprised because I was convinced that `onStart` would only be called after the execution of `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

FYI, I was trying to set a `MenuItem` as a global class variable in `onCreateOptionsMenu` to be able to use it in `onStart`. Of course I got a null pointer because of the execution order explained above.

It seems the more I dig into the Fragment's lifecycle, the more I am lost and the documentation only details the main methods, never the ones such as `onCreateOptionsMenu`, `onPrepareOptionsMenu`, `onCreateContextMenu` etc.

Does someone has any additional information about this, the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) is not really helpful...

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Check this out https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle. There you can see a full lifecycle for both fragment and activity.